# Wordpress uploaded video not play in Html 5 tag?

Tags: php, wordpress, html

```
<?php

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'attachment',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_status' => null,
  'post_parent' => null, // any parent
  'post_mime_type' => 'video/mp4'
); 

$attachments = get_posts( $args );

if ( $attachments ) {
  foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title( );
  //  the_attachment_link( $post->ID, false );
?>  
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="<?php     wp_get_attachment_link( $post->ID, false ); ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<?php


    the_excerpt( );
  }
}

?>
```

I have uploaded mp4 videos on wordpress media but I can't play in html5 tag I don't know where I am going wrong any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

follow the below article and make sure you have provided atleast two html5 video formats,

http://www.betterhostreview.com/add-html5-videos-wordpress.html

you can convert your video file to html5 video format from any html5 video converter apps or you can see the below url,

http://www.betterhostreview.com/free-video-converter-convert-html5-videos-freemake.html